# SQLite, read and parse a fairly large amount of data

Tags: c#, sqlite, gtfs

I am reading latitudes and longitudes (as doubles) from a fairly large SQlite table. Using an external tool (DB Browser for Sqlite) the query takes 200ms to execute (over 2 millions results). However, in my code (same query) it takes around 8-10 seconds. Here is the code (C# using Sytem.Data.Sqlite):

```
string sql = "SELECT shape_pt_lat, shape_pt_lon FROM shape";
List<double> lats = new List<double>();
List<double> lons = new List<double>();
using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = sql;
    SQLiteDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(r.Read())
    {
        lats.Add(r.GetDouble(1));
        lons.Add(r.GetDouble(2));
    }
}
```

I realize that a lot of time may be taken in parsing the doubles but I wrote a sample application that was able to parse 4 million doubles in 600ms. I am open to any suggestions to speeding this up, and could look at possibly processing it in parallel? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I guess it will not help a lot, but you can set initial size for the lists. It will reduce number of array allocations greatly. Allocation at large object heap is expensive, so you'd better do it once.

Comment: How fast is it without the `Add` calls?

Comment: Good question, it takes just over a second without the add calls. Is there any way to read all the data into an array at once and then parse the records in parallel?@JurySoldatenkov I'll try that, could improve things slightly.